# Backbone, How to memorize search results?

Tags: javascript, search, backbone.js, coffeescript

In my Backbone Application, on search results page I have link to #show action. This show action will show specified model.

-search results URI

```
/search
```

-specified model URI

```
/:modelName/:viewName/:id
```

(As you see I pass also modelName and viewName as parameters to Router action)

When user is on show page he should have option to return to search results (for example: button "Back to search results"). Search results have pagination so it will be unwise to fetch them again and again. Also fetching records will lose `collection` state.

I want to memoize search results.

Here goes the code for search (`Backbone.Router` action)

```
  search: (query) =>
    sentencesCollection = new SI.Collections.Sentences()
    searchParamSets = new SI.Collections.SearchParamSets()

    sentencesView = new SI.Views.SentencesSearchForm(
      collection: sentencesCollection
      searchParamSets: searchParamSets
    )
    resultsView = new SI.Views.SearchResults(
      collection: sentencesCollection
      searchParamSets: searchParamSets
      viewName: "SentencesShow"
    )
    @searchView.show(sentencesView)
    @contentView.show(resultsView)
    @sidebarView.show(new SI.Views.SentencesSearchFilters(
      searchParamSets: searchParamSets
    ))

    new SI.Views.SearchParamSets(collection: searchParamSets)

    if query?
      searchParamSets.reset({name: query})
      sentencesView.appendSearchSetAndGetSentences()
```

If user click "Back" button, `search` action in `Router` will be triggered. I want to use the same objects, not recreating them again. So basically this code will need refactor.

**My question:**

***How to memorize search results?***

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://underscorejs.org/#memoize

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you do not create collection for each search query. You first create a collection of queries, then you invoke input listener. Each query than is added to collection. Each time query is added, you check using `get()`, e.g. `queryCollection.get({ query: q })`. If it returns undefined, you do a XHR call. Otherwise your result is already in the collection.